# Why last xtick of my PGFPlots graph is not showing?

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I'm trying to draw a graph in Overleaf.
I'm using this template that I found online:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={C++ Threads performance},
    xlabel={Number of particles},
    ylabel={Time [ms]},
    xtick={10,50,100,1000},
    ytick={2317,3612,9122,85937},
        legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
       xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    % for log axes, x filter operates on LOGS.
    % and log(x * 1000) = log(x) + log(1000):
    x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1 + 6.90775527898214},
    ymode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    % for log axes, x filter operates on LOGS.
    % and log(x * 1000) = log(x) + log(1000):
    x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1 + 6.90775527898214}
]

    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    table {
    0.002 1500
    0.01 3676
    0.02 4439
    0.2 39850
    1
    };
    \addlegendentry{2 threads}
    \addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    table {
    0.002 2429
    0.01 2636
    0.02 2708
    0.20 15570
    1 93690
    };
    \addlegendentry{4 threads}
```

It worked very well until I decided to add one more tick to the x-axis
`xtick={10,50,100,1000,5000},`
The problem is that in the graph the 5000 tick is not showing:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
In order to reach the result I wanted:

[image]

I had to fix the table coordinates:

```
    table {
0.01 2429
0.05 2636
0.1 2708
1 15570
5 93690
};
```